# what does p in GdipCreateTexture stand for?

Tags: c++, vb.net, image, gdi+, gdi

I'm new to GDI+ and GDI, I notice some api are Gdi**plus**Shutdown，some are Gdi**p**CreateFromeHWND. does p stands for pointer? or they use p not plus for short. Or have something to do with flat api? I'm very confused. 
I was reading this website: http://www.yfvb.com/help/gdiplus/indexh.htm and http://e.125.la/api-s40.html. TIA.

Comment: Putting `GdipCreateFromeHWND` into to Google: _"...did not match any documents..."_ so it's some internal API you have found.  Please provide a link to reference documentation.

Comment: Just so you know, gdi & gdi+ are deprecated according to Microsoft.

Comment: @Richard Critten. http://e.125.la/api-7435.html I was reading this website. http://e.125.la/api-s40.html  Thanks.

Comment: @machine_1 New Microsoft deprecates everything that isn't the latest .NET fad.

Comment: "p" probably stands for "plus"

Comment: GDI+ has both a C and a C++ api.  The C function names are prefixed with Gdip, it still means "plus".  The C++ api is the much better documented one, its names are prefixed with Gdiplus.  That api was just meant to make it easier to use, it still relies on the C api to get the job done.  So the Graphics::Graphics(HWND) constructor simply calls GdipCreateFromHWND().  Mapping is [shown here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-graphics-flat).  Don't let any of these irrelevant details change the way you write your code.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, your  answer is very informative and helpful.